# Как работают клиент-серверные приложения?

Tags: клиент-сервер

Не понимаю, как работает эта технология. (( Например, если взять трояна, то клиент кидается юзеру, а сервер на сайт, что ли? Потом заходить и изменять код для новых команд? И как вообще клиент понимает, что есть новые команды? Ставиться таймер и через каждые 5000мс, например, отсылается запрос? Или как? Объясните, пожалуйста, а то я уже запутался...

P.S. Необязательно вирус, я просто для примера привел, ибо интересно, любая клиент-сервер программа имеется в виду.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[@gear](/users/25775/gear)](/users/25775/gear), у вас каша в голове.

> клиент кидается юзеру

Да, пользователь работает с клиентом, поэтому он и называется "клиент".

> сервер на сайт, что ли

Сервер, как ни странно, на сервер. Сайт это частный случай сервера.

> потом заходить и изменять код для новых команд?

Чтобы новый функционал появился на сервере, его очевидно нужно обновить.

- Это может быть и новая сборка сервера, которая заменяется целиком, после чего сервер перезапускается. Клиенты, если они непрерывно соединены с сервером, вынуждены будут установить связь повторно.
- Это может быть какая-то логика, вынесенная в скрипты или иные внешние модули - тогда достаточно их опубликовать там, где сервер их найдет, сервер при этом продолжит работать без остановки (так, например, обновляются php-файлы при обновлении сайта, а сервер Apache продолжает работать как ни в чем не бывало).
- Это может быть "горячая" замена кода - характерно для виртуальных машин.

> как вообще клиент понимает, что есть новые команды? ставиться таймер и через каждые 5000мс, например, отсылается запрос?

Грубо говоря, так. Чтобы клиент "узнал" о новых командах, он должен обновиться. Для этого обновления проверяются по какому-то расписанию. Раз в день, раз в неделю, раз в год. В зависимости от задач. При наличии обновления клиент его выкачивает и обновляется одним из вышеупомянутых способов. Так обновляются, например, приложения на телефоне.

Comment: Как тогда обновляются облака? Например, Яндекс.Диск, при изменении любого файла на облаке через телефон тут же включается синхронизация и на компе

Comment: Приближенно: клиент Яндекс.Диска у вас на компьютере узнает от серверов Яндекса, что есть изменения и надо их скачать.

Comment: то есть, как я понял, сервер не может прислать запрос клиенту первым, да? Мол, я обновился, присылай мне свой запрос... сначала, клиент должен запросить, а сервер ответить, так? Получается, клиент Яндекс.Диск делает запросы каждую секунду?

Comment: > сервер не может прислать запрос клиенту первым

Может, если клиент непрерывно держит соединение с сервером.

Comment: черт.. есть что-нибудь почитать, связанное именно с этим?

Comment: Для начала с основами разберитесь. Дальше все станет понятно.

![TCP/IP][1]

  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/Qz9iDJj.jpg

Comment: Конечно, сервер может прислать запрос клиенту первым, но надо знать, куда слать. Учитывая, что у большинства провайдеров динамический IP (а еще всякие роутеры наружу стоят за NAT'ом), то ценность данной стратегии очень сильно падает (в отличие от сервер-сервер соединений). Вот и приходится клиенту слать запросы по расписанию, а серверу просто слушать и отвечать. Просто потому, что у сервером статический IP, да еще порой записанный в DNS базу.

Answer (score 0):

Банкомат - клиент
В банке - сервер